# ошибка при попытке переключения одного Tab на другой в TabPane

Tags: javafx, tab

У меня есть TabPane и в нем три Tab каждый со своей разметкой, мне нужно было, чтобы по  событию в одном из них в  TabPane открывался другой Tab, написала вот такой кусочек кода для такого переключения, но почему то он вызывает исключение в главном методе https://pastebin.com/VJust56X

при удалении и отменении всех изменений исключение исчезает, что делать?

---

```
SelectionModel selectionMode;
    @FXML
    public TabPane mainTabPane;
    @FXML
    public Pane pane;

    @FXML
    public Tab potokTab;

    public void makeKonstructor(Konstructor konstructor){
        this.konstructor = konstructor;
        konstruktorMaked = true;
        selectionMode = mainTabPane.getSelectionModel();
       selectionMode.select(potokTab);
      mainTabPane.setSelectionModel((SingleSelectionModel<Tab>) selectionMode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем выносить `selectionModel` в переменную и переустанавливать ее?
Вот вам простой пример переключения таба по событию (способ инициализации `TabPane` не существеннен, т.е. можете использовать полученный из `fxml`)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
        final Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 2");
        Tab tab3 = new Tab("Tab 3");

        final TabPane tabPane = new TabPane(tab1, tab2, tab3);

        Button button = new Button("Select twoPane");
        button.setOnAction(e -> tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tab2));
        // or by index
//        button.setOnAction(e -> tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(1));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(button, tabPane)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```